# How to get sources of all images on page and then put them all in one division

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

What I want is that before the page loads, it gets all the images on the page, and puts them into one single division.
eg. The page has 5 images - eg1.png, eg2.jpg, eg3.bmp, eg4.jpg, eg5.png. Now before page starts to load, all the images remain in the page, but also go to a division with the id'pre'.  I want this to be done dynamically, so that if I change the images on the page, the images on the division also change.
HTML:-

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
     <img src="eg1.png">
     <img src="eg2.jpg">
     <img src="eg3.bmp">
     <img src="eg4.jpg">
     <img src="eg5.png">
</div>
<div id="pre">//all the images in 'content-wrapper' should also appear here//</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put an image in a `div`, that has 'pre' set as id:

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#pre').append("<img src='"+ src +"' /><br>");
});
```

But when I change the `src` attribute:

```
$("img").one("load", function() {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Could you please formulate an actual question? Also, it would help to show us the 'pre' `div` in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example code http://jsfiddle.net/fpWWT/1/

and simple jQuery function for what you need

```
$('img').each(function(){
 var src = $(this).attr('src')+'<br>';
  $('#pre').append(src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first get all the images source, add it into an array. Then load those images to cache and show them in the pre div. Until then show the LOADING image of something in pre div.
And also make the division content-wrapper **display:none** so that users cant see what is happening behind the scenes.
Here is the code

```
var $images = $("#content-wrapper img");

//in case you want to show progress bar
var $totalImages = $images.length;

//lets make a array to hold the images
var $imageHolder = []; 

//now lets add the images to cache

$images.each(function(i){
     var $img = new Image();
     $img.onload = function(){
           $imageHolder.push($img); 
           }
     $img.src = $(this).attr('src');
     });

//now that all your images are loaded into the cache add them to your div
$.each($imageHolder,function(i,item){
$("#pre").append(item);
});

//Done
```

And this will be totally dynamic ,, doesn't matter how many images you have got in the wrapper div.